# is android sherlock actionbar the same as UINavigationBar in iOS?

Tags: android, ios, actionbarsherlock, uinavigationbar

I come from iOS development, with some basic android apps done,

now im using a android sherlock actionbar,

I dont have clear if this is the same in iphone [iOS] as a UINavigationBar?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Actionbar is an incredibly useful UI widget for Android, having roughly the same appearance as the UINavigationBar on iOS, except with Android specific UI paradigms (context menu integration, tabs, progress loaders and more).

You'll quickly discover though, that the Actionbar only existed natively from Honeycomb (Android 3.x) onwards. So how do we get the Actionbar into projects that use earlier Android versions?

Android's achilles heel is the massive and somewhat fragmented ecosystem. For some reason to do with economics, market demographics or perhaps pure disdain for developers, some manufacturers insist on making devices for Android 2.x - rather than the newer 4.x version of Android. In this instance it's better to use a third party library called ActionbarSherlock by Jake Wharton. ActionbarSherlock (ABS) is basically a support library that will enable most Actionbar features on versions earlier than 2.x, with a few extra options to boot.